# Effect of aeration on Celerity

Tags: waves, density, oceanography

Suppose a ocean wave encountered a section of ocean which had a higher level of aeration from gas such as methane escaping from the seafloor.

Due to the aerated sections apparent lower density would the wave travel slower through aerated section than its propagation speed thru pure seawater ?

Comment: What do you think? What is your difficulty?

Comment: Hi @sammygerbil ,I was expecting perhaps not in that the medium isnt stable (as it is experiencing localized buoyant forces) and consequently I also thought that perhaps that its celerity would be affected by those  buoyant force opposing the restoring force in half the wavelength and increases the restoring force over the other half. what are your thoughts ?